# Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, laravel

I have setLocale in compiled.php file

when i tried to create a project i got

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 17054:
Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/project/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Lang/en.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/scrum/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/var/www/html/scrum/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/share/php')
```

my function

```
 $this['config']->set('app.locale', $locale);
        $this['translator']->setLocale($locale);
        $this['events']->fire('locale.changed', array($locale));

 static::translator()->addResource('array', require '/var/www/html/scrumwala/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon' . '/Lang/' . $locale . '.php', $locale);
where $locale=en
```

please help me

Comment: Where are you calling your function? Which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you have local cache in the project. Try this
`php artisan clear-compiled` 
clears the cache